# HP zbook studio G5 not adjustable brightness 18.04 gnome

Tags: drivers, nvidia, brightness

Coming from arch where i was unable to control brightness no matter what i tried, i realized that by using the nvidia-390 driver in ubuntu everything is working fine....BUT i have random crashes of the system. When I am using the nouveau drivers everything is fine BUT i do not have any control over the brightness of the screen.
This is a hybrid laptop and i have intel graphics and nvidia quadro P1000
Currently I am using the nouveau drivers
[Picture showing the 2 drivers available](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6V1m5.png)

Also please note that the intel graphics is not recognized at all.

**Some information about my system**

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1cbb (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 8429
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 255
    Memory at e8000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at a0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at b0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
    I/O ports at 4000 [size=128]
    Expansion ROM at e9000000 [disabled] [size=512K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau
```

and

```
$ inxi -G
Graphics:  Card: NVIDIA Device 1cbb
           Display Server: x11 (X.Org 1.19.6 ) drivers: fbdev,nouveau (unloaded: modesetting,vesa)
           Resolution: 1920x1080@77.00hz
           OpenGL: renderer: llvmpipe (LLVM 7.0, 256 bits) version: 3.3 Mesa 18.2.2
```

I have also attempted to use the brightness-controller application but it has no effect.

**How can I either fix the brightness using nouveau drivers or fix the random crashed with the nvidia driver?**

Answer (score 0):

Bios Upgrade:HP Firmware Pack (Q71)
    01.08.00 Rev.A  18.9 MB Aug 14, 2019

Nvidia Driver upgrade from 390 -> 430 (using ubuntu 18.04 proprieraty drivers)

Resolved my issues with instability/crashes AND brightness buttons

Comment: updated just before, 5 min later still crashes. I am on ubuntu 19.04 currently with nvidia-driver 430

Comment: im on 18.04 with kernel 5.0.0.25 , my crashes occured only after waking up from hibernation, which seems to be fixed.